# No me permite guardar 100 campos en mi BD

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la duda de que he intentado ver porque no me deja guardar los 100 datos al mismo tiempo, yo se que es mucho pero asi me pidieron hacer mi proyecto y queria ver como hacerlo funcionar, una vez reduje la cantidad de campos a 35 y si me los guarda pero 100 ya no, porque?

```html
<?php

$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "gobbc");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexion fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET a=1")) {
    printf("Codigo de error: %d\n", mysqli_errno($link));
}
    
$campo1=$_POST['campo-nombre'];        
$campo2=$_POST['campo-rfc'];      
$campo3=$_POST['campo-departamento'];       
$campo4=$_POST['campo-puesto'];       
$campo5=$_POST['campo-serv'];      
$campo6=$_POST['campo-prox_serv'];       
$campo7=$_POST['campo-fecha'];       
$campo8=$_POST['campo-marca'];      
$campo9=$_POST['campo-cpu'];      
$campo10=$_POST['campo-proc_mod'];       
(...)
$campo90=$_POST['campo-UsuSIGGO'];
$campo91=$_POST['campo-contraSIGGO'];
$campo92=$_POST['campo-UsuNom'];
$campo93=$_POST['campo-contraNom'];
$campo94=$_POST['campo-UsuUABC'];
$campo95=$_POST['campo-contraUABC'];
$campo96=$_POST['campo-UsuDIGI'];    
$campo97=$_POST['campo-contraDIGI'];
   
if (!$link->query("INSERT INTO tbarchivos
(
Nombre, RFC, Departamento, Puesto, Servicios, Prox_Serv, Fecha_Formato, Marca, CPU, Pro_Mod, Pro_velocidad, Memoria_MB, Memoria_tipo, Memoria_MHz, Disco_GB, Disp_impresoraL, Disp_impresoraR, Disp_escaner, Disp_lectorH, Disp_firma, Disp_certificadora, Inv_CPU, Inv_monitor, Inv_teclado, Inv_impresora, Inv_escaner, Inv_lectorHD, Inv_firma, Inv_certificadora, Inv_regulador, Red_equipo, Red_grupo, Red_IP, Red_nodo, Tel_ext, Tel_clave, Tel_monto, Tel_tipo, Tel_nodo, Ver_SO, Ver_office, Ver_acrobat, Ver_autocad, Ver_Corel, Ver_photoshop, Ver_Bizagui, Sist_correo_usu, Sist_correo_cont, Sist_maquina_usu, Sist_maquina_cont, Sist_Citrix_usu, Sist_Citrix_cont, Sist_SIRHB_usu, Sist_SIRHB_cont, Sist_DGIExp_usu, Sist_DGIExp_cont, Sist_SIVA_usu, Sist_SIVA_cont, Sist_SIP_usu, Sist_SIP_cont, Sist_BM_usu, Sist_BM_cont, Sist_SAIPBC_usu, Sist_SAIPBC_cont, Sist_SIGMA_usu, Sist_SIGMA_cont, Sist_SEARH_usu, Sist_SEARH_cont, Sist_PSYCOWIN_usu, Sist_PSYCOWIN_cont, Sist_Reloj_usu, Sist_Reloj_cont, Sist_RPPS_usu, Sist_RPPS_cont, Sist_Repbaj_usu, Sist_Repbaj_cont, Sist_magisterio_usu, Sist_magisterio_cont, Sist_magisterio_BD, Sist_VALIJA_usu, Sist_VALIJA_cont, Sist_consumos_usu, Sist_consumos_cont, Sist_compras_usu, Sist_compras_cont, Sist_PortComp_usu, Sist_PortComp_cont, Sist_SIBI_usu, Sist_SIBI_cont, Sist_SIGGO_usu, Sist_SIGGO_cont, Sist_NomEsp_usu, Sist_NomEsp_cont, Sist_UABC_usu, Sist_UABC_cont, Sist_DIGISIBI_usu, Sist_DIGISIBI_cont
        )
        VALUES
        (
        '$campo1', '$campo2', '$campo3', '$campo4', '$campo5', '$campo6', '$campo7', '$campo8', '$campo9', '$campo10', '$campo11', '$campo12', '$campo13', '$campo14', '$campo15', '$campo16', '$campo17', '$campo18', '$campo19', '$campo20', '$campo21', '$campo22', '$campo23', '$campo24', '$campo25', '$campo26', '$campo27', '$campo28', '$campo29', '$campo30', '$campo31', '$campo32', '$campo33', '$campo34', '$campo35', '$campo36', '$campo36', '$campo37', '$campo38', '$campo39', '$campo40', '$campo41', '$campo42', '$campo43', '$campo44', '$campo45', '$campo46', '$campo47', '$campo48', '$campo49', '$campo50', '$campo51', '$campo52', '$campo53', '$campo54', '$campo55', '$campo56', '$campo57', '$campo58', '$campo59', '$campo60', '$campo61', '$campo62', '$campo63', '$campo64', '$campo65', '$campo66', '$campo67', '$campo68', '$campo69', '$campo70', '$campo71', '$campo72', '$campo73', '$campo74', '$campo75', '$campo76', '$campo77', '$campo78', '$campo79', '$campo80', '$campo81', '$campo82', '$campo83', '$campo84', '$campo85', '$campo86', '$campo87', '$campo88', '$campo89', '$campo90', '$campo91', '$campo92', '$campo93', '$campo94', '$campo95', '$campo96', '$campo97')"))
{
   echo "Falló multi-INSERT: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
}
   
mysqli_error($link);
mysqli_close($link);
    
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso me sale a la hora de guardar los datos

Comment: El mensaje te dice que el número de campos y el de valores no coincide y que falla por eso. Aparte, una tabla con cien campos hace sospechar de un mal diseño y el nombre de los campos refuerza esa sensación, te recomiendo que estudies la normalización de bases de datos.

Comment: ¿Seguro que te pidieron guardar 100 campos o son 100 registros?

Comment: Si finalmente son cien campos, genera el SQL mediante un bucle, mete los valores en un array donde los indices sean los nombre de los campos y genera la sentencia de forma automática. P.e: `$datos['Departamento'] = 10`

Comment: Aparte de lo mencionado: tu código es vulnerable a inyección SQL.